# What's the meaning of 'couldn't make your car'?

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions, verbs, context

It was a situation that the police were trying to stop a driver who ran two stop signs. The driver finally got out of the car and said "I couldn't make your car".

From a [publication article](http://eprints.ums.ac.id/96584/9/Publication%20Article.pdf) by Sadah Al Janah:

> Ted: "Hi, officer. I think I must be lost."
> Officer: "You ran two stop signs, son."
> Ted: "I know. I…Couldn't make your car. The
> highlight were in my eyes, and to be honest, I
> got a little bit spooked"

Can anyone please explain what it implies in this context?

Comment: Where did you get this from? The driver's words here don't seem to mean anything at all (there is no expression *to be able to "make" another vehicle on the road* in English). Have you perhaps mistranscribed *I couldn't **shake** your car* (I wasn't able to drive fast enough to get clean away, and stop you from following me)?

Comment: (There are no instances of "**Couldn't make the** [police | patrol | squad] **car**" in Google Books.)

Comment: Are you sure they didn't say *Couldn't make your car **out***?

Comment: @yosef: Could you make this an answer, preferably with some authoritative sources?

Comment: Given the other usage mistakes apparent in the dialogue in that script(?), I think it was probably intended to mean "I couldn't make out" (see) "your car" like @PeterShor suggested.  A couple rows down in the table from where this appears, there's *"Excuse me, deputy? He needs to
use phone call in a library."*  Where it should be "needs to *make a* phone call in the library".  Or some other possibility, but anyway, given two instances of mangled grammar within a few lines, I'd expect the whole document to have more.

Answer (score 6):

"Couldn't make your car" = **Couldn't decode your car as a police car.**

"To make" is American police code for making out *or spotting* that a plain-clothes officer is an undercover cop:

> I think he just made me.

So, "I couldn't make your car" would mean ...

> No sh!t. Gott in Himmel. Ay Dios mio! Are you the police? Couldn't tell, or I would have stopped earlier! But that's me. My bad. Not angry, are ya?

*Need citation here.*
I hear the phrase *He made me!* on the TV series of Law & Order and on Chicago PD.